# Android app on eclipse keeps shutting down

Tags: java, android, eclipse

The app runs on my phone, but as soon as I  press the "please press to start" Button on the main Activity, it just shuts down.
I know this problem has something to do with my GameActivity.java Class, but can't find the problem with it.

```
package com.example.battleships;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class GameActivity extends Activity {
    private ImageView mMyImage1, mMyImage2, mMyImage3, mMyImage4, mMyImage5,
            mMyImage6, mMyImage7, mMyImage8, mMyImage9, mMyImage10, mMyImage11,
            mMyImage12, mMyImage13, mMyImage14, mMyImage15, mMyImage16,
            mMyImage17, mMyImage18, mMyImage19, mMyImage20, mMyImage21,
            mMyImage22, mMyImage23, mMyImage24, mMyImage25;

    public static final String PlayerName = "com.example.battleships.Name";

    public ImageView[] mYimage = { mMyImage1, mMyImage2, mMyImage3, mMyImage4,
            mMyImage5, mMyImage6, mMyImage7, mMyImage8, mMyImage9, mMyImage10,
            mMyImage11, mMyImage12, mMyImage13, mMyImage14, mMyImage15,
            mMyImage16, mMyImage17, mMyImage18, mMyImage19, mMyImage20,
            mMyImage21, mMyImage22, mMyImage23, mMyImage24, mMyImage25 };

    private int[] nums = { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 };
    private int myCount = 0, Count = 8;
    private String GamerName;
    private TextView myText;
    private Drawable bomb, clown;

    Drawable startImage;

    @Override
    // Method
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        GamerName = getIntent().getStringExtra(PlayerName);
        myText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        myText.setText("Hi, " + GamerName + "! You have" + Count + "attempts.");

        while (myCount<5){
            int j = (int)(Math.random()*25);
            if (nums[j] != 2){
                nums[j] = 2;
                myCount++;
            }

        }

        startImage = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

        mMyImage1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView1);
        mMyImage1.setImageDrawable(startImage);
        mMyImage2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        mMyImage2.setImageDrawable(startImage);
        mMyImage3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
        mMyImage3.setImageDrawable(startImage);
        mMyImage4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
        mMyImage4.setImageDrawable(startImage);
        mMyImage5 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
        mMyImage5.setImageDrawable(startImage);
        mMyImage6 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView6);
        mMyImage6.setImageDrawable(startImage);
        mMyImage7 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView7);
        mMyImage7.setImageDrawable(startImage);
        mMyImage8 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView8);
        mMyImage8.setImageDrawable(startImage);
        mMyImage9 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView9);
        mMyImage9.setImageDrawable(startImage);
        mMyImage10 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView10);
        mMyImage10.setImageDrawable(startImage);
        mMyImage11 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView11);
        mMyImage11.setImageDrawable(startImage);
        mMyImage12 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView12);
        mMyImage12.setImageDrawable(startImage);
        mMyImage13 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView13);
        mMyImage13.setImageDrawable(startImage);
        mMyImage14 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView14);
        mMyImage14.setImageDrawable(startImage);
        mMyImage15 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView15);
        mMyImage15.setImageDrawable(startImage);
        mMyImage16 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView16);
        mMyImage16.setImageDrawable(startImage);
        mMyImage17 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView17);
        mMyImage17.setImageDrawable(startImage);
        mMyImage18 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView18);
        mMyImage18.setImageDrawable(startImage);
        mMyImage19 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView19);
        mMyImage19.setImageDrawable(startImage);
        mMyImage20 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView20);
        mMyImage20.setImageDrawable(startImage);
        mMyImage21 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView21);
        mMyImage21.setImageDrawable(startImage);
        mMyImage22 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView22);
        mMyImage22.setImageDrawable(startImage);
        mMyImage23 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView23);
        mMyImage23.setImageDrawable(startImage);
        mMyImage24 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView24);
        mMyImage24.setImageDrawable(startImage);
        mMyImage25 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView25);
        mMyImage25.setImageDrawable(startImage);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void action(View v) {
        Count--;
        v.getId();
        bomb = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bomb);
        clown = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.clown);

        switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.ImageView1:
            if (R.id.ImageView1 == v.getId()) {
                if (nums[0] == 2) {
                    mMyImage1.setImageDrawable(bomb);

                    myText.setText("Well Done, " + GamerName + "! You have"
                            + Count + "attempts.");
                } else {
                    myText.setText("Boo, " + GamerName + "! You have" + Count
                            + "attempts.");
                    mMyImage1.setImageDrawable(clown);

                }
                break;
            }

        case R.id.imageView2:
            if (R.id.imageView2 == v.getId()) {
                if (nums[1] == 2) {

                    mMyImage2.setImageDrawable(bomb);

                    myText.setText("Well Done, " + GamerName + "! You have"
                            + Count + "attempts.");
                } else {
                    myText.setText("Boo, " + GamerName + "! You have" + Count
                            + "attempts.");
                    mMyImage2.setImageDrawable(clown);

                }
                break;
            }
        case R.id.imageView3:
            if (R.id.imageView3 == v.getId()) {
                if (nums[2] == 2) {

                    mMyImage3.setImageDrawable(bomb);

                    myText.setText("Well Done, " + GamerName + "! You have"
                            + Count + "attempts.");
                } else {
                    myText.setText("Boo, " + GamerName + "! You have" + Count
                            + "attempts.");
                    mMyImage3.setImageDrawable(clown);

                }
                break;
            }
        case R.id.imageView4:
            if (R.id.imageView4 == v.getId()) {
                if (nums[3] == 2) {

                    mMyImage4.setImageDrawable(bomb);

                    myText.setText("Well Done, " + GamerName + "! You have"
                            + Count + "attempts.");
                } else {
                    myText.setText("Boo, " + GamerName + "! You have" + Count
                            + "attempts.");
                    mMyImage4.setImageDrawable(clown);

                }
                break;
            }
        case R.id.imageView5:
            if (R.id.imageView5 == v.getId()) {
                if (nums[4] == 2) {

                    mMyImage5.setImageDrawable(bomb);

                    myText.setText("Well Done, " + GamerName + "! You have"
                            + Count + "attempts.");
                } else {
                    myText.setText("Boo, " + GamerName + "! You have" + Count
                            + "attempts.");
                    mMyImage5.setImageDrawable(clown);

                }
                break;
            }
        case R.id.imageView6:
            if (R.id.imageView6 == v.getId()) {
                if (nums[5] == 2) {

                    mMyImage6.setImageDrawable(bomb);

                    myText.setText("Well Done, " + GamerName + "! You have"
                            + Count + "attempts.");
                } else {
                    myText.setText("Boo, " + GamerName + "! You have" + Count
                            + "attempts.");
                    mMyImage6.setImageDrawable(clown);

                }
                break;
            }

        case R.id.imageView7:
            if (R.id.imageView7 == v.getId()) {
                if (nums[6] == 2) {

                    mMyImage7.setImageDrawable(bomb);

                    myText.setText("Well Done, " + GamerName + "! You have"
                            + Count + "attempts.");
                } else {
                    myText.setText("Boo, " + GamerName + "! You have" + Count
                            + "attempts.");
                    mMyImage7.setImageDrawable(clown);

                }
                break;
            }

        case R.id.imageView8:
            if (R.id.imageView8 == v.getId()) {
                if (nums[7] == 2) {

                    mMyImage8.setImageDrawable(bomb);

                    myText.setText("Well Done, " + GamerName + "! You have"
                            + Count + "attempts.");
                } else {
                    myText.setText("Boo, " + GamerName + "! You have" + Count
                            + "attempts.");
                    mMyImage8.setImageDrawable(clown);

                }
                break;
            }
        case R.id.imageView9:
            if (R.id.imageView9 == v.getId()) {
                if (nums[8] == 2) {

                    mMyImage9.setImageDrawable(bomb);

                    myText.setText("Well Done, " + GamerName + "! You have"
                            + Count + "attempts.");
                } else {
                    myText.setText("Boo, " + GamerName + "! You have" + Count
                            + "attempts.");
                    mMyImage9.setImageDrawable(clown);

                }
                break;
            }
        case R.id.imageView10:
            if (R.id.imageView10 == v.getId()) {
                if (nums[9] == 2) {

                    mMyImage10.setImageDrawable(bomb);

                    myText.setText("Well Done, " + GamerName + "! You have"
                            + Count + "attempts.");
                } else {
                    myText.setText("Boo, " + GamerName + "! You have" + Count
                            + "attempts.");
                    mMyImage10.setImageDrawable(clown);

                }
                break;
            }
        case R.id.imageView11:
            if (R.id.imageView11 == v.getId()) {
                if (nums[10] == 2) {

                    mMyImage11.setImageDrawable(bomb);
                    myText.setText("Well Done, " + GamerName + "! You have"
                            + Count + "attempts.");
                } else {
                    myText.setText("Boo, " + GamerName + "! You have" + Count
                            + "attempts.");
                    mMyImage11.setImageDrawable(clown);

                }
                break;
            }
        case R.id.imageView12:
            if (R.id.imageView12 == v.getId()) {
                if (nums[11] == 2) {

                    mMyImage12.setImageDrawable(bomb);

                    myText.setText("Well Done, " + GamerName + "! You have"
                            + Count + "attempts.");
                } else {
                    myText.setText("Boo, " + GamerName + "! You have" + Count
                            + "attempts.");
                    mMyImage12.setImageDrawable(clown);

                }
                break;
            }
        case R.id.imageView13:
            if (R.id.imageView13 == v.getId()) {
                if (nums[12] == 2) {
                    mMyImage13.setImageDrawable(bomb);

                    myText.setText("Well Done, " + GamerName + "! You have"
                            + Count + "attempts.");
                } else {
                    myText.setText("Boo, " + GamerName + "! You have" + Count
                            + "attempts.");
                    mMyImage13.setImageDrawable(clown);
                }
                break;
            }

        case R.id.imageView14:
            if (R.id.imageView14 == v.getId()) {
                if (nums[13] == 2) {

                    mMyImage14.setImageDrawable(bomb);

                    myText.setText("Well Done, " + GamerName + "! You have"
                            + Count + "attempts.");
                } else {
                    myText.setText("Boo, " + GamerName + "! You have" + Count
                            + "attempts.");
                    mMyImage14.setImageDrawable(clown);

                }
                break;
            }
        case R.id.imageView15:
            if (R.id.imageView15 == v.getId()) {
                if (nums[14] == 2) {
                    mMyImage15.setImageDrawable(bomb);

                    myText.setText("Well Done, " + GamerName + "! You have"
                            + Count + "attempts.");// put in picture
                } else {
                    myText.setText("Boo, " + GamerName + "! You have" + Count
                            + "attempts.");// put in picture
                    mMyImage15.setImageDrawable(clown);// put in picture -
                }
                break;
            }
        case R.id.imageView16:
            if (R.id.imageView16 == v.getId()) {
                if (nums[15] == 2) {
                    mMyImage16.setImageDrawable(bomb);

                    myText.setText("Well Done, " + GamerName + "! You have"
                            + Count + "attempts.");// put in picture
                } else {
                    myText.setText("Boo, " + GamerName + "! You have" + Count
                            + "attempts.");// put in picture
                    mMyImage16.setImageDrawable(clown);// put in picture -
                }
                break;
            }
        case R.id.imageView17:
            if (R.id.imageView17 == v.getId()) {
                if (nums[16] == 2) {
                    mMyImage17.setImageDrawable(bomb);

                    myText.setText("Well Done, " + GamerName + "! You have"
                            + Count + "attempts.");// put in picture
                } else {
                    myText.setText("Boo, " + GamerName + "! You have" + Count
                            + "attempts.");// put in picture
                    mMyImage17.setImageDrawable(clown);// put in picture -
                }
                break;
            }
        case R.id.imageView18:
            if (R.id.imageView18 == v.getId()) {
                if (nums[17] == 2) {
                    mMyImage18.setImageDrawable(bomb);

                    myText.setText("Well Done, " + GamerName + "! You have"
                            + Count + "attempts.");// put in picture
                } else {
                    myText.setText("Boo, " + GamerName + "! You have" + Count
                            + "attempts.");// put in picture
                    mMyImage18.setImageDrawable(clown);// put in picture -
                }
                break;
            }
        case R.id.imageView19:
            if (R.id.imageView19 == v.getId()) {
                if (nums[18] == 2) {
                    mMyImage19.setImageDrawable(bomb);

                    myText.setText("Well Done, " + GamerName + "! You have"
                            + Count + "attempts.");// put in picture
                } else {
                    myText.setText("Boo, " + GamerName + "! You have" + Count
                            + "attempts.");// put in picture
                    mMyImage19.setImageDrawable(clown);// put in picture -
                }
                break;
            }
        case R.id.imageView20:
            if (R.id.imageView20 == v.getId()) {
                if (nums[19] == 2) {
                    mMyImage20.setImageDrawable(bomb);

                    myText.setText("Well Done, " + GamerName + "! You have"
                            + Count + "attempts.");// put in picture
                } else {
                    myText.setText("Boo, " + GamerName + "! You have" + Count
                            + "attempts.");// put in picture
                    mMyImage20.setImageDrawable(clown);// put in picture -
                }
                break;
            }
        case R.id.imageView21:
            if (R.id.imageView21 == v.getId()) {
                if (nums[20] == 2) {
                    mMyImage21.setImageDrawable(bomb);

                    myText.setText("Well Done, " + GamerName + "! You have"
                            + Count + "attempts.");// put in picture
                } else {
                    myText.setText("Boo, " + GamerName + "! You have" + Count
                            + "attempts.");// put in picture
                    mMyImage21.setImageDrawable(clown);// put in picture -
                }
                break;
            }
        case R.id.imageView22:
            if (R.id.imageView22 == v.getId()) {
                if (nums[21] == 2) {
                    mMyImage22.setImageDrawable(bomb);
                    myText.setText("Well Done, " + GamerName + "! You have"
                            + Count + "attempts.");// put in picture
                } else {
                    myText.setText("Boo, " + GamerName + "! You have" + Count
                            + "attempts.");// put in picture
                    mMyImage22.setImageDrawable(clown);// put in picture -
                }
                break;
            }
        case R.id.imageView23:
            if (R.id.imageView23 == v.getId()) {
                if (nums[22] == 2) {
                    mMyImage23.setImageDrawable(bomb);

                    myText.setText("Well Done, " + GamerName + "! You have"
                            + Count + "attempts.");
                } else {
                    myText.setText("Boo, " + GamerName + "! You have" + Count
                            + "attempts.");
                    mMyImage23.setImageDrawable(clown);
                }
                break;
            }
        case R.id.imageView24:
            if (R.id.imageView24 == v.getId()) {
                if (nums[23] == 2) {
                    mMyImage24.setImageDrawable(bomb);

                    myText.setText("Well Done, " + GamerName + "! You have"
                            + Count + "attempts.");
                } else {
                    myText.setText("Boo, " + GamerName + "! You have" + Count
                            + "attempts.");// put in picture
                    mMyImage24.setImageDrawable(clown);// put in picture -

                }
                break;
            }
        case R.id.imageView25:
            if (R.id.imageView25 == v.getId()) {
                mMyImage25.setImageDrawable(bomb);

                myText.setText("Well Done, " + GamerName + "! You have" + Count
                        + "attempts.");// put in picture
            } else {
                myText.setText("Boo, " + GamerName + "! You have" + Count
                        + "attempts.");// put in picture
                mMyImage25.setImageDrawable(clown);// put in picture -

            }
            break;
        }

        //if (Count == 0) {
            //endMethod();
    //  }
    }



    public void theEnd() {

        if (nums[0] == 2) {
            mMyImage1.setImageDrawable(bomb);
        } else {
            mMyImage1.setImageDrawable(clown);

        }
        if (nums[1] == 2) {
            mMyImage2.setImageDrawable(bomb);
        } else {
            mMyImage2.setImageDrawable(clown);
        }
        if (nums[2] == 2) {
            mMyImage3.setImageDrawable(bomb);
        } else {
            mMyImage3.setImageDrawable(clown);

        }
        if (nums[3] == 2) {
            mMyImage4.setImageDrawable(bomb);
        } else {
            mMyImage4.setImageDrawable(clown);
        }
        if (nums[4] == 2) {
            mMyImage5.setImageDrawable(bomb);
        } else {
            mMyImage5.setImageDrawable(clown);
        }
        if (nums[5] == 2) {
            mMyImage6.setImageDrawable(bomb);
        } else {
            mMyImage6.setImageDrawable(clown);
        }
        if (nums[6] == 2) {
            mMyImage7.setImageDrawable(bomb);
        } else {
            mMyImage7.setImageDrawable(clown);
        }
        if (nums[7] == 2) {
            mMyImage8.setImageDrawable(bomb);
        } else {
            mMyImage8.setImageDrawable(clown);
            if (nums[8] == 2) {
                mMyImage9.setImageDrawable(bomb);
            } else {
                mMyImage9.setImageDrawable(clown);
            }
            if (nums[9] == 2) {
                mMyImage10.setImageDrawable(bomb);
            } else {
                mMyImage10.setImageDrawable(clown);
            }
            if (nums[10] == 2) {
                mMyImage11.setImageDrawable(bomb);
            } else {
                mMyImage11.setImageDrawable(clown);
            }
            if (nums[11] == 2) {
                mMyImage12.setImageDrawable(bomb);
            } else {
                mMyImage12.setImageDrawable(clown);
            }
            if (nums[12] == 2) {
                mMyImage13.setImageDrawable(bomb);
            } else {
                mMyImage13.setImageDrawable(clown);
            }
            if (nums[13] == 2) {
                mMyImage14.setImageDrawable(bomb);
            } else {
                mMyImage14.setImageDrawable(clown);
            }
            if (nums[14] == 2) {
                mMyImage15.setImageDrawable(bomb);
            } else {
                mMyImage15.setImageDrawable(clown);
            }
            if (nums[14] == 2) {
                mMyImage16.setImageDrawable(bomb);
            } else {
                mMyImage16.setImageDrawable(clown);
            }
            if (nums[15] == 2) {
                mMyImage16.setImageDrawable(bomb);
            } else {
                mMyImage16.setImageDrawable(clown);
            }
            if (nums[16] == 2) {
                mMyImage17.setImageDrawable(bomb);
            } else {
                mMyImage17.setImageDrawable(clown);
            }
            if (nums[17] == 2) {
                mMyImage18.setImageDrawable(bomb);
            } else {
                mMyImage18.setImageDrawable(clown);
            }
            if (nums[18] == 2) {
                mMyImage19.setImageDrawable(bomb);
            } else {
                mMyImage19.setImageDrawable(clown);
            }
            if (nums[19] == 2) {
                mMyImage20.setImageDrawable(bomb);
            } else {
                mMyImage20.setImageDrawable(clown);
            }
            if (nums[20] == 2) {
                mMyImage21.setImageDrawable(bomb);
            } else {
                mMyImage21.setImageDrawable(clown);
            }
            if (nums[21] == 2) {
                mMyImage22.setImageDrawable(bomb);
            } else {
                mMyImage22.setImageDrawable(clown);
            }
            if (nums[22] == 2) {
                mMyImage23.setImageDrawable(bomb);
            } else {
                mMyImage23.setImageDrawable(clown);
            }
            if (nums[23] == 2) {
                mMyImage24.setImageDrawable(bomb);
            } else {
                mMyImage24.setImageDrawable(clown);
            }
            if (nums[24] == 2) {
                mMyImage25.setImageDrawable(bomb);
            } else {
                mMyImage25.setImageDrawable(clown);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: post please logcat message.

Comment: one sec, let me get it.

Comment: http://justpaste.it/kwpq

Comment: `NullPointerException` at line 56, which looks to be here `mMyImage1.setImageDrawable(startImage);`  Can you post your `activity_main` layout XML?

Comment: http://jpst.it/yDvO   is activity_main     http://jpst.it/yDw6   activity_game

Comment: Could be the string from the user in the main activity isn't being passed into the game activity?

Answer (score 0):

`ImageView1`, among others, does not exist in `R.layout.activity_main`

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
...
mMyImage1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView1);  // R.id.ImageView1 does not exist in layout activity_main...
mMyImage1.setImageDrawable(startImage);  // ...hence the NullPointerException here
```

I think you meant you use R.layout.activity_game?

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
```

Comment: Couldn't use R.id, id, warning said game activity couldn't be resolved, I used layout instead and it worked.

Comment: I meant to use that, but still getting issues with the app, it keeps on stopping after I enter text and save on the activity_main.